# Remove gmail calendar event through .ics file using php

Tags: php, calendar, icalendar

I have to delete a calendar event from gmail calendar through .ics file. My .ics file like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//xyz.com//NONSGML kigkonsult.se iCalcreator 2.18//
METHOD:CANCEL
X-WR-TIMEZONE:UTC
X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN:TRUE
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:93450@xyz.com
DTSTAMP:20170620T114123Z
DESCRIPTION:test description
DTSTART:20170621T070000Z
DTEND:20170621T073000Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:2
STATUS:CANCELLED
SUMMARY:test summary
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:DISPLAY
DESCRIPTION:test discription
TRIGGER:-PT0H15M0S
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

It is working fine for email client (outlook and Thunderbird) but not working for gmail calendar. Please give you suggestions to delete from gmail calendar

Comment: I think people are thinking how to help, do you have some code?

Comment: Above ics file is working for delete old event form outlook and thunderbird calendar but not working for gmail. if any changes required in above calendar code to delete from gmail, then suggest me.

Comment: What code works with thunderbird/outlook?

Comment: I am sending above icalendar file in attachment with (.ics) extention. Thunderbird and outlook read it as calendar email and they asking to remove event from calendar, if click on remove then event will delete from calendar.

Answer (score -1):

Right well, Thunderbird and outlook are both programs with calendars that are 'on the computer'. So they can probably do magical things with attachments such as preview and in this case remove/add/accept events. Gmail being online can't do such things browser security etc. So don't think you have many options.

Google Calendar does have an API which you could use. 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php

I would suspect you'll encounter similar problems for the Microsoft live calendar or perhaps other online calendars that people might use.

In the end you either need to supply a way to 'link' your application to the persons online calendar and use the API supplied (if it exists) or perhaps dodge the question entirely by supplying an online ics file through your own API that people can embed into there calendar (I know Outlook can do this). Or just don't have the ics files and instead just the calendar in your own application (which I think is where the ics files are coming from?)

Just a google seems to say the answer is a no -https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/9uHpOige9Co

Although...
http://blog.tomverhoeff.nl/2011/01/31/howto-undo-ical-import-in-google-calendar/